# Eclipse 2022-09 Icon in the dock has an error in it on MacBook M1

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, apple-m1, macbookpro-touch-bar

[image: Please see this image for the error in the dock]

Check the image, whenever I start Eclipse the logo gets that error after the software performs initial startup and deferred early start checks. Does anyone know how to fix this?
I can't stand that error message.

Comment: Makes running Eclipse with a fresh workspace ( `eclipse -data <workspace_dir>`) a difference (`...pace` might mean _workspace_)?

Comment: Just looks like a "badge app icon" notification rather than an error. Look in the Notifications & Focus in the System Preferences to see if it can be disabled.

Comment: I don't see an option to disable dock badges for eclipse, can someone help me find it if there is an option like that @greg-449

Comment: I'm not seeing this on my macOS (12.6), not sure where it is coming from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Eclipse, open Preferences and navigate to General → Workspace. Disable the "Show workspace name" option; this will remove it from the window title, as you would expect, but also from the Dock icon.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That red splat looked terrible. Works in Eclipse 2023-03 too.